# Commutator summation notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, terminology, commutator, lie-algebra

I have the relation $ e^L M e^{-L}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{n!} [L,M]_{(n)}$ where $L$ and $M$ are operators.
What does the subscript $n$ after the commutator bracket denote?

Comment: Can you please provide a reference to where the equation was found?

Comment: University lecture notes so password protected. See edit for full equation.

Comment: Yes sorry. Edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the Baker-Campbell-Haussdorff formula, and the notation means to iterate the commutator. That is, $$[L, M]_1 = [L, M]$$
And $$[L,M]_{n+1} = [L, [L,M]_{n}].$$

Comment: I was about to edit my answer to include this, but you beat me to it. A reference to this is [this section in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma).

Answer (score 3):

The notation is short-hand for an expression utilizing the Backer Campbell Haussdorf formula. Let $X$ and $Y$ be operators, then

$$e^{x}Ye^{-X} = Y + [X,Y] + \frac{1}{2!}[X,[X,Y]] + \frac{1}{3!}[X,[X,[X,Y]]] + ...$$

I assume $[X,Y]_{(n)}$ refers to the $n$th term in this expansion; it roughly counts how many times the commutators are nested in each other.

Comment: Damn, just beaten to it by 2 mins!

Answer (score 2):

This is not standard notation, and one would typically expect any text that uses it to define it at its first occurrence. Since you understandably cannot provide us with a reference, your best bet is hunting for all occurrences of that notation, starting from there and going up through the text, until it explains what it means. Trust me, it will be there.

Comment: ...or you just didn't attend enough lectures ;)